# stack excedeed in recursive function for reading JSON key-value and creating a string to append to the DOM

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom

I know there are a lot of similar questions here but they are different from mine. basically I have an Ajax call that return me an array of objects that are nested in more levels. the problem is that I don't know neither how many the levels are nor the property names of them. so I made a recursive function for extracting the data from it and build a string that I'm going to append to the Dom after reading all the keys and values inside the object.
the json is an array with inside three objects that have inside of them arrays of objects sometimes.I wrote this code:

```
$.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'/apiTlvArchive/tlvListAuditRecords',
      data:{
        xFilterObj:strObject
      },
      success:(result)=>{
        if(result.AuditRecords){
          AuditRecords=result.AuditRecords
          Docreatefiltersessiontable(AuditRecords)
        }
        
      },error:(error)=>{
        error.responseJSON.ErrorCode===9004 ? showErrorAlertMsg('Intervallo date seleionato troppo lungo') : showErrorAlertMsg('errore in list auditrecords')
        
      }
    })


  }
```

in the success callback I then call a function that is going to configure the table(I use datatables plugin) and inside this function I call the recursive function for reading the Json and creating a string that is gonna be appended to the DOM. the code is as follows:

```
function Docreatefiltersessiontable(AuditRecords){//crea tabella in tab filtra sessione
          let tablestring=''
          tablestring+=`<thead>
          <tr><th>Parametro</th><th>Valore</th></tr>
          </thead><tbody>`
         tablestring+= processObject(AuditRecords)
         tablestring+='</tbody>'
         document.getElementById('FiltersessionTable').innerHTML=tablestring
         FiltersessionTableinstance= $("#FiltersessionTable").DataTable({
          scrollY: 500,
          scrollX: false,
          scrollCollapse: false,
          deferRender: true,
          paging: true,
          ordering: false,
          searching: true,
          info: false,
          searchDelay: 350,
          pageLength: 50,
          columnDefs: [
            {
              "width": "15%",
              "targets": 0
            },
            {
              "width":"12%",
              "targets":1

            },
          ]
        });
  }
```

and finally the recurisve function:

```
function processObject(jsonObject) {
    let strSource=''
    for (var property in jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          if (typeof (jsonObject[property]) == 'object') {
            strSource+=processObject(jsonObject[property]);
           // processObject(jsonObject[property]);
          }
          if(isNaN(property) && typeof(jsonObject[property])!=="object"){//voglio escludere indici e object di object
           strSource+=`<tr>
                   <td>${property}</td>
                   <td>
                     ${jsonObject[property]}
                   </td>
                 </tr>`
           
          }
        }
      }
      return strSource;
  }
```

I get the stack exceedeed error only when I try to create the string inside of the function when the objects are a little more than usual. the fact is that the recursive function works fine for just reading the keys and values, but if i try to create something like the string, there's always the point where is gonna cause the stack excedeed error.I need to do a recursive function cause I don't know prior  the keys of this Json. Any idea on how to fix this problem? is there another solution or recursion is the only one I have?
i'll leave the JSON structure here if someone wants to see it [JSON structure here](https://pastebin.com/XvX82upN)

Comment: Maybe you need to check if the property is an array and process that differently.

Comment: other than keep looking at the object what can I do?

Comment: You should check if `jsonObject[property]` is `null` before recursing. `typeof(null) == 'object'`

Comment: Because typeof null is object ... You're right. That's one thing to add but I don't think it'll help me in the stack exceed problem...

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of is if there are circular references within the object. But you can't get circularity from JSON.

Comment: How can I have a null as a key in JSON object returned from the server? I'm doing the for loop for every key that the JSON object have...

Comment: I called your function with the JSON object you link to and it worked fine.

Comment: Not null key, null value. `jsonObject[property]` could be null.

Comment: When I run your code I don't get an error and the output looks like table data.  I took your processObject function, and your sample data from pastebin, and did `const output = processObject(result.AuditRecords)`, and I get valid output.  [check it](https://jsfiddle.net/543dkmue/)

Comment: As I wrote it works for certain numbers of objects..if the response from the server is too big is gonna cause the stack exceeded issue. In pastebin I just copied one object from the array not everything

Comment: The only thing that makes sense to me is that the input is malformed, that instead of a number of parallel objects, you are nesting deeper and deeper.  Your sample is only eight layers deep.  That will have no recursion-depth issues.  But if you accidentally have nested them deeper and deeper, it would explain the issue.  If they are intentionally nested really deeply, then you will need an alternative to plain recursion in modern JS engines, perhaps trampolining, or a manually maintained recursive stack.

Comment: @Scott never heard about trampoline in JavaScript... Can you provide an example of my recursive function written in that way? By having a look seems to wrap my function with another one and transform it to a simple for loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+trampoline

Comment: @ScottSauyet sorry to bother you again, can you provide me my recursive function written in the trampoline way? I'm trying to understand it and as a beginner it seems difficult to implement.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how StackOverflow works.  We're here to help you with your technical problems, not to write your code for you..

Comment: @ScottSauyet you're right. Can I ask you one thing about my recursive function that I have difficulty to understand?

Comment: I'd suggest that it might be better to open a new question specifically for that.  (You can add a link back to this one for more context.)  Feel free to mention me in a comment, and if I have time, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to replicate your problem, it will probably be hard to solve.  But one way to simplify the problem, and therefore possibly solve it, is to break it down into smaller parts.  If we first convert your object into the following structure and then format it into a table in a separate step, you might be able to more easily isolate the issue:

```js
[
  ["AccessToken$s", "B3A3863E1011EAC178514C4A567FC4E3F0182583B0B4"],
  ["BaseCode$s", "RAI"],
  ["EMailAddress$s", ""],
  ["ErrorCode$i32", 9000],
  // ...
  ["ConditionalAccessSubcode$s", "$SYSTEM"],
  ["0", "AccessAdmin"],
  ["1", "AccessDefaults"],
  ["2", "AccessInserters"],
  // ...
  ["34", "ViewSchedules"],
  ["35", "WriteFastTextlinks"],
  ["ProfileCode$s", "ADMINISTRATOR"],
  // ...
  ["UserDomain$s", "PRODTV"]
]
```

Moreover, this leaves us with a more general-purpose function to extract the leaf keys and values.  And the whole system is simpler.  We might do that like this:

```js
const getLeaves = (o) => 
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object .entries (o) .flatMap (([k, v]) => Object (v) === v ? getLeaves (v) : [[k, v]])
    : [[]]

const makeTable = (o) => 
  getLeaves (o) 
    .filter (([k, v]) => ! k .match (/^\d+$/))
    .map (([k, v]) => `<tr><td>${k}</td><td>${v}</td></tr>`) .join ('\n')

const input = {"AuditRecords": [{"Answer": {"AccessToken$s": "B3A3863E1011EAC178514C4A567FC4E3F0182583B0B4", "BaseCode$s": "RAI", "EMailAddress$s": "", "ErrorCode$i32": 9000, "ErrorMessage$s": "", "LanguageCode$s": "IT", "MenuCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectsAccess": [{"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/MOTORI/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/MOTORI/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$MASTERPAGES", "ObjectType$i32": 77, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$MASTERPAGES", "OjectType$i32": 77, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "ListInserters", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "ListInserters", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "TXTLV", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "TXTLV", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGES", "ObjectType$i32": 80, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGES", "OjectType$i32": 80, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": true, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/ULTIMORA/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/ULTIMORA/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGES", "ObjectType$i32": 80, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGES", "OjectType$i32": 80, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "MASTER100RICHIAMITESTA", "ObjectType$i32": 77, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "MASTER100RICHIAMITESTA", "OjectType$i32": 77, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "NAZIONALE", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 73, "OjectCode$s": "NAZIONALE", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 73, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/OGGIEDICOLAZ/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/OGGIEDICOLAZ/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": true, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/RUBRICHE/INDICEOGGI/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/RUBRICHE/INDICEOGGI/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "FLASH", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "FLASH", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGESETS", "ObjectType$i32": 83, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/INDICE/GENERALE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$USERPAGESETS", "OjectType$i32": 83, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": true, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$INSERTERS", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 105, "OjectCode$s": "$INSERTERS", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 105, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "FFF", "ObjectType$i32": 80, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/NOTIZIE/CULTURE/", "OjectSubcode$s": "FFF", "OjectType$i32": 80, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "GIOVEDI", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "GIOVEDI", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": false, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "RAI1", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 105, "OjectCode$s": "RAI1", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 105, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": true}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": false, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "ObjectSubcode$s": "404_405", "ObjectType$i32": 67, "OjectCode$s": "$MANUAL", "OjectSubcode$s": "404_405", "OjectType$i32": 67, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}, {"CreateFlag$b": false, "DeleteFlag$b": true, "ExecuteFlag$b": false, "ObjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/RUBRICHE/TESTCARTELLA/", "ObjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ObjectType$i32": 70, "OjectCode$s": "/CYCLONE/NAZIONALE/GIORNALE/RUBRICHE/TESTCARTELLA/", "OjectSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OjectType$i32": 70, "ReadFlag$b": true, "UpdateFlag$b": false}], "PhoneNumber$s": "", "PublisherPort$ui16": 28901, "RefreshToken$s": "B3A3863E1011EAC178514C4A567FC4E3F0182583B0B4", "RestrictedFlag$b": false, "ServerCode$s": "TLVCOLLECTOR", "ServerId$s": "18236", "ServerProjectVersion": {"ComponentVersions": [{"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "ZipUtils.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}, {"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "CoreUtils.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}, {"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "DatabaseUtils.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}, {"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "FrameworkDefines.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}, {"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "FrameworkCoreUtils.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}, {"BuildNumber$i32": 1, "ComponentName$s": "FrameworkServerUtils.dll", "LoadLibraryFlag$b": true, "MajorVersion$i32": 2, "MinorVersion$i32": 5, "ResolveFlag$b": true, "TagVersion$s": "ML"}]}, "SessionCode$s": "18236.20220502082154.0", "SessionId$i32": 5, "SessionToUtcSeconds$i32": 0, "SessionType$s": "TLV", "SupervisorFlag$b": true, "TokenExpireSeconds$i32": 3600, "TrainingFlag$b": false, "UserCode$s": "ADMIN", "UserOperations": [{"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPermessiTapiXml"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AllocatePageNumber"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ViewLogs"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AlterMailProperties"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "MaintenanceUtilities"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessAdmin"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "EditPage"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "Attributes"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPacket83"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "PutOnTakOffAir"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "BaseAccessPM"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ViewArchives"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPublishSchema"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "UnlockPages"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ModifyIndexControl"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "SerialConnection"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ExchangeSlots"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ModifyNewsreel"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "Shuffle"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "SystemConfiguration"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "WriteFastTextlinks"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessInserters"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPermessiMonitor"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "BatchRun"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPublisher"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessDefaults"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "FolderManagement"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessTopText"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "EditScript"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "CopyContent"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "PagePurge"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "DeletePage"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AccessPermessiOggetti"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "ViewSchedules"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "AutoLogon"}, {"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCode$s": "BaseAccessSM"}], "UserProfiles": [{"ConditionalAccessCode$s": "$SYSTEM", "ConditionalAccessSubcode$s": "$SYSTEM", "OperationCodes$s": ["AccessAdmin", "AccessDefaults", "AccessInserters", "AccessPacket83", "AccessPermessiMonitor", "AccessPermessiOggetti", "AccessPermessiTapiXml", "AccessPublisher", "AccessPublishSchema", "AccessTopText", "AllocatePageNumber", "AlterMailProperties", "Attributes", "AutoLogon", "BaseAccessPM", "BaseAccessSM", "BatchRun", "CopyContent", "DeletePage", "EditPage", "EditScript", "ExchangeSlots", "FolderManagement", "MaintenanceUtilities", "ModifyIndexControl", "ModifyNewsreel", "PagePurge", "PutOnTakOffAir", "SerialConnection", "Shuffle", "SystemConfiguration", "UnlockPages", "ViewArchives", "ViewLogs", "ViewSchedules", "WriteFastTextlinks"], "ProfileCode$s": "ADMINISTRATOR"}]}, "Header": {"BaseCode$s": "RAI", "ConnectionDateTime$dt": "2022-05-02T08:21:54", "CurrentMsTimeUTC$i64": 20220502082154370, "ErrorCode$i32": 9000, "ErrorMessage$s": "", "HostName$s": "localhost", "LoggedFlag$b": true, "RunId$i64": 20220502082034880, "ServerCode$s": "TLVCOLLECTOR", "ServiceCode$s": "TlvLogin", "ServiceGroupCode$s": "", "SessionCode$s": "18236.20220502082154.0", "SessionId$i32": 5, "SupervisorFlag$b": true, "UserCode$s": "ADMIN"}, "Request": {"HostName$s": "localhost", "Password$s": "189BBBB00C5F1FB7FBA9AD9285F193D1", "ServerCode$s": "TLVCOLLECTOR", "ServiceCode$s": "TlvLogin", "UserCode$s": "ADMIN", "UserDomain$s": "PRODTV"}}]}

console .log (makeTable (input))
```

**`getLeaves`** does this first conversion, and **`makeTable`** calls `getLeaves`, filters out the numeric keys, then turns them the remaining entries into `<tr><td>...` strings and merges them into a single string.

Comment: I wrapped maketable and getleaves in a function and then instead of console.log I do return maketable and still throws the excedeed stack error. this also happens with my implementation. if I just console log it works fine, if I build the string and then return it I have the stack exceed problem. Dunno what to think https://pastebin.com/ARcvT9Xu

Comment: here is the JSON https://github.com/edoremo00/json I have to push it in a repo because the file it's too large for pastebin. it's a 7MB json file

Comment: I am able to run this.  Are you also building DOM nodes from that HTML string?  Could it be failing there?  It builds and logs the string properly for me in https://link.fourwindssoft.com/54, using your long file, with 144k+ leaf nodes.